How to find out which directory a PBS jobs was submitted from while it is still in the queue?
How to find out which directory a PBS job was submitted from? I guess that information is stored in the variable $PBS_O_WORKDIR. But I do not know how to access this variable while the job is still queued (waiting to run)?
I have tried qstat -f <job_id> with no luck.
